# Antlr parser for and/or logic - how to get expressions between logic operators?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr3

I am using ANTLR to create an and/or parser+evaluator. Expressions will have the format like:

- `x eq 1 && y eq 10`
- `(x lt 10 &&  x gt 1) OR x eq -1`

I was reading this post on logic expressions in ANTLR [Looking for advice on project. Parsing logical expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368191/looking-for-advice-on-project-parsing-logical-expression) and I found the grammar posted there a good start:

```
grammar Logic;

parse
  :  expression EOF
  ;

expression
  :  implication
  ;

implication
  :  or ('->' or)*
  ;

or
  :  and ('&&' and)*
  ;

and
  :  not ('||' not)*
  ;

not
  :  '~' atom
  |  atom
  ;

atom
  :  ID
  |  '(' expression ')'
  ;

ID    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
Space : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

However, while getting a tree from the parser works for expressions where the variables are just one character (ie, `"(A || B) AND C"`, I am having a hard time adapting this to my case (in the example `"x eq 1 && y eq 10"` I'd expect one `"AND"` parent and two children, `"x eq 1"` and `"y eq 10"`, see the test case below).

```
@Test
public void simpleAndEvaluation() throws RecognitionException{
    String src = "1 eq 1 && B";

    LogicLexer lexer = new LogicLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(src));
    LogicParser parser = new LogicParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));


    CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.parse().getTree();

    assertEquals("&&",tree.getText());
    assertEquals("1 eq 1",tree.getChild(0).getText());
    assertEquals("a neq a",tree.getChild(1).getText());
}
```

I believe this is related with the `"ID"`. What would the correct syntax be?

Comment: Posted here as well: http://antlr.markmail.org/message/bk6kutcu56vuglgl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested, I made some improvements in my grammar file (see bellow)

Current limitations:

- only works with &&/||, not AND/OR (not very problematic)
- you can't have spaces between the parenthesis and the &&/|| (I solve that by replacing " (" with ")" and ") " with ")" in the source String before feeding the lexer)

  grammar Logic;

  ```
  options {
    output = AST;
  }

  tokens {
    AND = '&&';
    OR  = '||';
    NOT = '~';
  }

  // parser/production rules start with a lower case letter
  parse
    :  expression EOF!    // omit the EOF token
    ;

  expression
    :  or
    ;

  or
    :  and (OR^ and)*    // make `||` the root
    ;

  and
    :  not (AND^ not)*      // make `&&` the root
    ;

  not
    :  NOT^ atom    // make `~` the root
    |  atom
    ;

  atom
    :  ID
    |  '('! expression ')'!    // omit both `(` and `)`
    ;

  // lexer/terminal rules start with an upper case letter
  ID
    :
      (
      'a'..'z'
      | 'A'..'Z'
      | '0'..'9' | ' '
      | SYMBOL
    )+ 
    ;

  SYMBOL
    :
      ('+'|'-'|'*'|'/'|'_')
   ;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
ID    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
```

states that an identifier is a sequence of one or more letters, but does not allow any digits. Try

```
ID    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9')+;
```

which will allow e.g. `abc`, `123`, `12ab`, and `ab12`. If you don't want the latter types, you'll have to restructure the rule a little bit (left as a challenge...)

In order to accept arbitrarily many identifiers, you could define `atom` as `ID+` instead of `ID`.

Also, you will likely need to specify `AND`, `OR`, `->` and `~` as tokens so that, as @Bart Kiers says, the first two won't get classified as `ID`, and so that the latter two will get recognized at all.

Comment: @Aasmund, that doesn't take into consideration 2 things I believe: the fact that a token can have spaces ("green neq green" should be one token). Also, using AND/OR instead of &&/||, shouldn't one need to say in the ID something like ~and && ~or (or ~"AND", ~"OR") ?

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset: If you change the atom to ID+ but don't add "| ' '" to the ID, aren't you saying you expect IDID...ID, ie, 1eq1 (without the spaces)? That grammar tokenizes 1 eq 1 || B into a parent || and 4 children ( 1,eq,1,B), not 2 children (1 eq 1,B).