# ANTLR4: Parser for a Boolean expression

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to parse a boolean expression of the following type
B1=p & A4=p | A6=p &(~A5=c)

I want a tree that I can use to evaluate the above expression. So I tried this in Antlr3 with the example in [Antlr parser for and/or logic - how to get expressions between logic operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509048/antlr-parser-for-and-or-logic-how-to-get-expressions-between-logic-operators)

It worked in Antlr3. Now I want to do the same thing for Antlr 4. I came up the grammar below and it compiles. But I am having trouble writing the Java code.

### Start of Antlr4 grammar

```
grammar TestAntlr4;

options {
  output = AST;
}

tokens { AND, OR, NOT }

  AND : '&';
  OR  : '|';
  NOT : '~';


// parser/production rules start with a lower case letter
parse
  :  expression EOF!    // omit the EOF token
  ;

expression
  :  or
  ;

or
  :  and (OR^ and)*    // make `||` the root
  ;

and
  :  not (AND^ not)*      // make `&&` the root
  ;

not
  :  NOT^ atom    // make `~` the root
  |  atom
  ;

atom
  :  ID
  |  '('! expression ')'!    // omit both `(` and `)`
  ;

// lexer/terminal rules start with an upper case letter
ID
  :
    (
    'a'..'z'
    | 'A'..'Z'
    | '0'..'9' | ' '
    | ('+'|'-'|'*'|'/'|'_')
    | '='
  )+ 
  ;
```

---

I have written the Java Code (snippet below) for getting a tree for the expression "B1=p & A4=p | A6=p &(~A5=c)". I am expecting & with children B1=p and |. The child | operator will have children A4=p and A6=p &(~A5=c). And so on. 
Here is that Java code but I am stuck trying to figure out how I will get the tree. I was able to do this in Antlr 3.

### Java Code

```
String src = "B1=p & A4=p | A6=p &(~A5=c)";
CharStream stream = (CharStream)(new ANTLRInputStream(src));
TestAntlr4Lexer lexer = new TestAntlr4Lexer(stream);
parser.setBuildParseTree(true);
ParserRuleContext tree = parser.parse();
tree.inspect(parser); 
if ( tree.children.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println(" **************");
    test.getChildren(tree, parser);
}
```

The get Children method is below. But this does not seem to extract any tokens.

```
public void getChildren(ParseTree tree, TestAntlr4Parser parser ) {
   for (int i=0; i<tree.getChildCount(); i++){
       System.out.println(" Child i= " + i);
       System.out.println(" expression = <" + tree.toStringTree(parser) + ">");
       if ( tree.getChild(i).getChildCount() != 0 ) {
           this.getChildren(tree.getChild(i), parser);
       }
   }
}
```

Could someone help me figure out how to write the parser in Java?

Answer (score 3):

The `output=AST` option was removed in ANTLR 4, as well as the `^` and `!` operators you used in the grammar. ANTLR 4 produces *parse trees* instead of ASTs, so the root of the tree produced by a rule is the rule itself. For example, given the following rule:

```
and : not (AND not)*;
```

You will end up with an `AndContext` tree containing `NotContext` and `TerminalNode` children for the `not` and `AND` references, respectively. To make it easier to work with the trees, `AndContext` will contain a generated method `not()` which returns a list of context objects returned by the invocations of the `not` rule (return type `List<? extends NotContext>`). It also contains a generated method `AND` which returns a list of the `TerminalNode` instances created for each `AND` token that was matched.

Comment: I am new to ANTLR and I am still trying to figure out how I can grab the nodes in the expression B1=p & A4=p. I need the result B1=p and the other child node as A4=p so that I can evaluate it. Can you please explain further how I can print the nodes out with some code.

Comment: @AshwiniBhandary, instead of walking the tree manually, I suggest you use ANTLR4's built-in functionality to do so. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610183/if-else-statements-in-antlr-using-listeners
 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050137/once-grammar-is-complete-whats-the-best-way-to-walk-an-antlr-v4-tree